# ECS Service Connect DNS Resolution

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cloudmap

I am trying to get ECS Service Connect to work our services. But for some reason, just not able to get it to work.
What we have in place:

- One service (`admin`) needs to get some data from another service (`metrics`).
- Both services are deployed on ECS
- The containers in both services are using the `awsvpc` network mode
- Service Connect has been configured for both services

[Service Connect for Metrics Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pk3yL.png)

[Service Connect for Admin Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L38xF.png)

Both services are in the same cluster and using the same Service Connect Namespace (`service-discovery-cluster`).
This is reflected in CloudMap entry for the Namespace.

[CloudMap entries for the services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4BUx.png)

So far, all this was as expected. And the services are accessible via an ALB and working fine.
However, I would have expected that the Admin Service can call the Metric service with `http://metrics.service-discovery-cluster` (the recommended `http://service-dns.cluster` pattern), but this cannot be resolved by the HTTP Library.

I know I am missing something very basic somewhere but just can't work it out.

Could someone help out, please?

Other details:

1. I am using Unirest with Java (I don't think that should matter, but still)
2. All tasks have `awsvpc` networking mode
3. Exact error: `java.net.UnknownHostException: metrics.service-discovery-cluster: Name or service not known`

I tried using ports for the services (e.g., `http://metrics.service-discovery-cluster:8084`), but that didn't work either.

Comment: is there any firewall? and make sure the required port is open for both server ip on security groups check that also

Comment: The ports are open in the SG. As mentioned, I can call the API through the ALB. Not sure what you meant by Firewall here though. The Admin Service is calling Metrics Service and both are hosted in the same ECS Cluster and same namespace.

Answer (score 2):

Since a DNS name is specified, the service connect endpoint would be `http://metrics:8084`.

If this (optional) DNS field is *not* specified, then the endpoint would be `http://metrics.service-discovery-cluster:8084` (the recommended pattern).

The service connect endpoints that are created for an ECS service are visible in the **Configuration and networking** tab -> **Service Connect** section of the service in the ECS management console.

---

For the service connect configuration shown below, wherein a DNS name is specified for one,

[service_connect_configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HShm.png)

the endpoints created are as shown below

[service_connect_endpoints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6q5u4.png).